# Rust trait and its default implementation

Tags: rust, traits

Wrote a trait that checks a given number(u16 or u32) is even or not.

v1.0

```
trait EvenOdd {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool;
}

impl EvenOdd for u16 {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
        self % 2 == 0
    }
}

impl EvenOdd for u32 {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
        self % 2 == 0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: u16 = 11;
    let y: u32 = 44;

    println!("x = {}, y = {}", x.is_even(), y.is_even());
}
```

This runs fine.  But since `is_even` is repeated for `u16` and `u32`, moved it into the trait as a default method.

v2.0

```
trait EvenOdd {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
        self % 2 == 0
    }
}

impl EvenOdd for u16 {
}

impl EvenOdd for u32 {
}

fn main() {
    let x: u16 = 11;
    let y: u32 = 44;

    println!("x = {}, y = {}", x.is_even(), y.is_even());
}
```

This produces compiler error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `%` cannot be applied to type `&Self`
 --> trait_arithmetic_v2.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         self % 2 == 0
  |         ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Rem` might be missing for `&Self`
```

Attempting to constrain `&self` results in compiler error:

```
fn is_even<T: std::ops::Rem> (&self: T) -> bool
    self % 2 == 0
}

error: expected one of `)` or `,`, found `:`
 --> trait_arithmetic_v2.rs:2:44
  |
2 |         fn is_even<T: std::ops::Rem> (&self: T) -> bool {
  |                                            ^ expected one of `)` or `,` here
```

The only way I could apply the constraint is by changing the `is_even` api.

v3.0

```
use std::ops::Rem;

trait EvenOdd {
    fn is_even<T: Rem<Output = T> + PartialEq + From<u8>> (&self, other: T) -> bool {
        other % 2.into() == 0.into()
    }
}
```

And use it like `x.is_even(x)` which is un-natural.  How to fix my v2.0?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `v2.0` the compiler doesn't know the type that you are trying to apply the arithmetic operation and `trait EvenOdd: Rem` doesn't work because `Rem` takes `Self`.

This code is somewhat limited but works for your example and it is functional because there is a default implementation of `impl From<u16> for u32`.

```
use std::ops::Rem;

trait EvenOdd {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool;
}

impl<T> EvenOdd for T
where
    T: Copy + From<u16> + PartialEq + Rem<Output=T>
{
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
        *self % From::from(2u16) == From::from(0u16)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: u16 = 11;
    let y: u32 = 44;

    println!("x = {}, y = {}", x.is_even(), y.is_even());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Caio.  Somehow, sad that other parameters are constrainable whereas `self` is not.

Comment: @recsubbu `self` is constrainable, its type is `Self`, so you can constrain it in a `where` clause like so: `fn is_even(&self) -> bool where Self: Rem<Output = Self> + PartialEq + From<u8> { ... }`